# LG L5 restarts every minute

Tags: boot-loop, reboot, lg-optimus-l5

I don't know what I've done to my LG L5, but now it's just restarting and restarting.
I've rooted my phone using adb and installed ClockworkMod recovery, but now it just restarts every time it loads into phone or into ClockworkMod.

I really don't know what to do. Even if I get new ROM onto sdcard and try to flash my phone, it could randomly (in 1 min) shutdown, and I guess then I will brick my phone. So what should I do? I've tried to wipe cache/data/dalvik cache.

At first I could get to my home screen and even work for a while, but now I can't even go to my home screen. It freezes on the boot logo and restarts after 1 minute. Even in ClowkworkMod recovery. Works one minute and restarts.

Is there something that could help me?

**Ok, so for now I've updated to cyanogenmod, thought it'll help, but no. It just keeps restarting, but now it goes to home screen again. So what to do? How can I update kernel or whatever I need to do?**

Comment: This is strange. Sounds to me like a kernel issue, have you tried flashing a new kernel/bootloader using fastboot?

Comment: Where can I find new kernel, and how I even can load them, if my phone now just don't load up... only loops in logo screen..

Comment: What should I do? adb devices returns nothing else than empty string... I can't even go to home screen anymore.. it just freezes for a minute on my LG logo screen (startup) and after minute restarts...

Comment: Can you get to recovery?

Comment: Yes.. but again only for 1 minute

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis Did you manage to find a solution for this? I believe I might be face the same issue with my LG L5 (E610/612(f))